# why homogeneity test is used for ANOVA not for t test?

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity

Why the homogeneity test must be curried out for ANOVA test but not for t-test when sample size is more than 30 ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you ask "why" you should ask "if".

Homogeneity of variance tests *are* carried out for t-tests. At least, SAS `PROC TTEST`carries them out, and R's `t.test`assumes (by default) that they are not equal. E.g.

```
 t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep)
```

performs a Welch t.test and gives df = 17.78, whereas

```
  t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep, var.equal = TRUE)
```

performs a (regular) t-test with df = 18. Even with large N and normally distributed data, R assumes unequal variances:

```
x1 <- rnorm(1000, 0, 10)
  x2 <- rnorm(1000, 0.8, 10)

  t.test(x1,x2)
```

performs a Welch test.